# Syntax error in INSERT INTO Statement when writing to Access

Tags: .net, database, vb.net, ms-access, oledb

I am trying to write a program where I can write data to an Access DB but I keep getting the error “Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement”.

`FirstLast` is the name of the table; `First` and `Last` are columns in it.

```vb
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Form1
    Dim theConnectionString As New OleDbConnection
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        theConnectionString.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\user\Documents\Database1.accdb"

        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO FirstLast (First, Last) VALUES (@First, TextBox1.text)", theConnectionString)

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@First", OleDbType.Char, 255).Value = TextBox1.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Last", OleDbType.Char, 255).Value = TextBox1.Text

        Try
            theConnectionString.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw ex
        Finally
            theConnectionString.Close()
        End Try

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You’re naming your parameters `@First` and `@Last` — so shouldn’t you use those instead of `?` in the query?

Comment: @mwilson: No, they should be switched for your *parameter* names. Those don't have to be the same as your column names at all.

Comment: I'm hardly an Access expert, but isn't the *actual* problem simply that you have `VALUES (@First, TextBox1.text)` in your SQL, where it *should* say `VALUES (@First, @Last)`? If so, I'm voting to close this question as "merely a typo".

Answer (score 5):

I suspect you just need to use named parameters instead of positional ones:

```
INSERT INTO FirstLast (First, Last) VALUES (@First, @Last)
```

Note that you should also use `Using` statements for the connection and command, so that you clean up after yourself automatically without needing an explicit `Finally` block. (You can get rid of your entire `Try`/`Catch`/`Finally` given that you're just rethrowing the exception anyway.)

As noted in the comment below, you also probably meant to use `TextBox2.Text` for the `@Last` parameter, rather than using `TextBox1.Text` again.

Comment: Also the @Last value is wrong.  You most likely want to use TextBox2.Text

Comment: Do I need any special imports for this? I still can't get it working...

I don't quite follow on the Try Catch yet. I am still learning that portion. Is it okay as is or is this causing the issue?

Comment: @mwilson: No, you don't need any extra imports. "I still can't get it working" is far too vague for me to help you, I'm afraid... and I'm about to get on a plane. If you're not familiar with Try/Catch blocks I suggest you stop what you're doing and learn about them. It's not a good idea to use code with language features you don't understand. It means you've got very little chance of being able to diagnose problems yourself.